# Callback after two asynchronous functions

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, callback

I want to call `UseScreenshots` after my two `html2canvas` have been called.

```
function Main()
{
    var screenshot1, screenshot2;

    html2canvas($('#div1'),
    {
        onrendered: function (canvas)
        {
            screenshot1 = canvas.toDataURL('image/png');
        }
    });

    html2canvas($('#div2'),
    {
        onrendered: function (canvas)
        {
            screenshot2 = canvas.toDataURL('image/png');
        }
    });

    UseScreenshots(screenshot1, screenshot2);
}
```

In the example above `screenshot1` and `screenshot2` will still be `undefined` when calling `UseScreenshots`.

---

Following **deceze**'s answer, I'll use [Promise.all](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all):

```
Promise.all(
[
    new Promise(function (resolve) 
    {
        html2canvas($('#div1'), 
        {
            onrendered: function (canvas) 
            {
                resolve(canvas.toDataURL('image/png'));
            }
        });
    }, 
    new Promise(function (resolve) 
    {
        html2canvas($('#div2'), 
        {
            onrendered: function (canvas) 
            {
                resolve(canvas.toDataURL('image/png'));
            }
        });
    }
]).then(function (screenshots) 
{ 
    UseScreenshots(screenshots[0], screenshots[1]);
});
```

Comment: The code doesn't make much sense to me. Can you come up with SSCCE?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Promises can solve exactly this case very elegantly:

```
Promise.all([new Promise(Function1), new Promise(Function2)]).then(Function3);
```

See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all.
You'll need to adapt `Function1` and `Function2` to use promises correctly, or perhaps even to return promises themselves, or wrap them appropriately.

Sample to create one promise:

```
new Promise(function (resolve) {
    html2canvas($('#div1'), {
        onrendered: function (canvas) {
            resolve(canvas.toDataURL('image/png'));
        }
    });
})
```

You'll receive the resolved values as an array in your `.then` callback:

```
Promise.all([..]).then(function (screens) { UseScreenshots(screens[0], screens[1]); });
```

Comment: Thanks but it says not to be supported by IE which is a problem for me.

Comment: I added an example. Be sure to read the documentation to become familiar with promises as a concept.

Comment: There are independent promise implementations you can add as a dependency to polyfill for IE.